# jquery countdown from 4 seconds to 0 then at 0 move on to next function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to program a sort of game where you have 4 seconds to do answer a question (verbally) and once it's up it moves on to the next question. I need it to play audio (not what im asking here), then countdown from 4 seconds to 0 and then display the correct answer and move on.

How can I create a countdown that goes from 4 to 0 seconds and then after moves on to the next thing?

I've tried the following and have failed.

```
    var counter = 4;

    $('#seconds').html(counter);

    function decreaseSeconds(){
        counter--;
        $('#seconds').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#seconds').html(counter).delay(800);
        $('#seconds').fadeIn('fast');
    }

    while ( counter > 0){
         decreaseSeconds()
    }
```

Comment: You could try using the `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4FXHp/1/)

```
var nextFunction = function () {
  alert('Hello.');
};

sec = 4;

interval = setInterval(function () {
  sec--;
  document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = sec;

  if (sec == 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    nextFunction();
  }
}, 1000); ​
```

Comment: where do i put the next function which must be called once it reaches 0?

Answer (score 1):

You should use setTimeout

```
yourfirstfunction ();
setTimeout (yoursecondfunction, counter*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use setTimeout from pure javascript? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Some thing like this: http://jsfiddle.net/collabcoders/MD6sz/2/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var secs = 4;
  ticker = setInterval(function(){
    $("#timer").html(secs + " seconds left");
    if (secs == 0) {

      //call some function when the clock hits 0
      $("#timer").html("time is up");
      clearInterval(ticker);
    }
    secs --;
  }, 1000);
});​
```